# If I can smell my trash in my garage from the room above it, should I be concerned about other vapors?

Tags: insulation, garage, safety, smell

We just bought a new construction home. We have some trash in our garage bin that does have a potent smell, but I assumed it'd stay confined to the garage. This evening while putting my daughters to bed, I noticed I could smell the trash faintly throughout their room - I could smell it enough to know it was the trash from the garage though.

It seems if the vapors from a trash bin can reach through their floor (literally directly above the garage -- we can feel the garage door vibrate in their floor), other more harmful vapors (co2 from the car? vapors from hot water heater?) could seep in too.

Should I be concerned about this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, maybe if you have a gas boiler installed in that space,as some people might, or your cars are inefficient. Consider installing Carbon Monoxide detectors, as CO poisoning can be a concern. Its odourless, and can damage by binding to haemoglobin.

Answer (score 0):

Your garage is probably not properly sealed. It's a fairly common issue, sadly. Few people think of off-gassing from cars putting fumes into living areas. I would also venture to say that you might not have a properly insulated garage ceiling either.

Things I would do

1. Check to make sure they completely sealed the garage. Corners are the most common culprits. They should be drywall taped and/or caulked (if they put up crown)
2. Check for open/unfinished areas in the drywall. Enclose them if they are present.
3. Cut a small hole in the garage ceiling drywall. Make sure there's insulation there or you may have a nasty surprise come Winter